# How to style a label with a colon

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a details view window in WPF and a label may look like this.

```
<Label Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.Reference}" />
```

So that is obtains it content from my property Resource.

How can transform/format the content so it has a colon after each label item.  e.g. instead of the content simply displaying Reference I want it to transform to Reference:

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.Reference}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"/>
```

Comment: Strangely enough - this was one of the earlier solutions I tried and it would not work?  I have since discovered that sometimes the 'wysiwyg' window does not update correctly until I do a full compile !

Comment: same thing here in VS2017 Pro

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `Binding` with `StringFormat` to format the result.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resource.Reference}, StringFormat='{}{0}:'}"
```

Note that the `{}` before the format string is here to prevent the XAML parser from treating `{0}` as a markup extension, like `{StaticResource}` for example.

Comment: Thank-you for your response.  For some strange reason I could not get your suggestion to work, but it did set me on the right course to a solution which was:  Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.Date}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"